# Como elaborar um algoritmo que escreva os números ímpares entre 100 e 200?

Tags: algoritmo, lógica

Estou preso nessa questão que eu vi em um [PDF de logica de programação](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~vania/teaching/ine5231/Logica.pdf), como posso resolver isso?

> Elabore um algoritmo que gera e escreve os números ímpares dos números lidos entre 100 e 200.

Comment: Se tentou fazer alguma coisa, edite a pergunta e adicione o código nela, também explique o que não funciona ou qual é a dúvida em especifico.

Comment: Olá, Xanda, editei sua pergunta para deixá-la mais profissional e sem cara de dever de casa. Não tem problema fazer perguntas simples aqui, porém é legal que você demonstre seus esforços por achar uma solução e dar mais detalhes como menciona o rray. Por exemplo, já leu o ítem "7.2 Comandos de Repetição"? . . . . . .  Pesquisar aqui dentro do [pt.so] também é importante, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aimpar

Answer (score 5):

Você terá que fazer um `for` entre os valores 100 e 200, se o resto da divisão por 2 for diferente de 0, o número é ímpar.